# How do I fill a column with a user inputted value?

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I want to add a date column to data exported to csv file. Luckily the files are identified by the date they represent. However, I can't get the column to fill up with the appropriate user inputted value. Here's the code I have so far:

```
def read_file():
    user_input = raw_input("Please put cost folder with date in form Costmm.dd: ")
    path = r'C:\\Users\\CP\\documents\\' + user_input
    allFiles = glob.glob(path + '/*.csv')
    frame = pd.DataFrame()
    frame['Date'] = pd.Series()
    frame['Date'] = frame['Date'].astype(object).fillna(user_input)

    list = []
    for file in allFiles:
        df = pd.read_csv(file,index_col=None,header=0)
        list.append(df)
    frame =pd.concat(list,ignore_index=True)
    frame['Date'] = pd.Series()
    return(frame)
```

Any and all help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please show the format of `user_input`, also you should be able to replace `frame = pd.DataFrame()
    frame['Date'] = pd.Series()
    frame['Date'] = frame['Date'].astype(object).fillna(user_input)` with just `frame = pd.DataFrame({'Date':[pd.to_datetime(user_input)]})`

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by format, user_input is a string I thought.

Comment: It must be a date string correct? so what's the format? is it `'dd/mm/yyyy'? is it `'July 23 2011'`?

Comment: Oh sorry, the format is 'mm.dd'

Comment: So are you trying to store just a string or a datetime object? Also your code is nonsense, you create a df, then assign an empty series, then try to set the date for that column, then overwrite it with the result of concatenating all the dfs in a list and then set the date column to an empty series?!

Comment: I was just trying to store the string but would also love to be able to make it into a datetime object

Comment: I am super new at this so I would also appreciate you pointing out how to improve the code overall! And the second line frame['Date'] = pd.series() is an error and should not be there! I apologize

Comment: the fact remains your code as it stands does nothing with it as you overwrite it with the result of `concat`, but after the concat line you should change `frame['Date'] = pd.Series()` to `frame['Date'] = pd.to_datetime([user_input], format='%m.%d')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you're after the following should work:

```
import datetime as dt
def read_file():
    user_input = raw_input("Please put cost folder with date in form Costmm.dd: ")
    path = r'C:\\Users\\CP\\documents\\' + user_input
    allFiles = glob.glob(path + '/*.csv')

    l = []
    for file in allFiles:
        df = pd.read_csv(file,index_col=None,header=0)
        l.append(df)
    frame =pd.concat(l,ignore_index=True)
    frame['Date'] = dt.datetime.strptime(user_input, '%m.%d')
    return frame
```

A few notes:

```
frame = pd.DataFrame()
frame['Date'] = pd.Series()
frame['Date'] = frame['Date'].astype(object).fillna(user_input)
```

The above was redundant as you overwrite this with the result of `pd.concat` anyway.

Don't user `list` for a variable name of type `list` use something like `df_list`.

To convert a string to datetime you can use `dt.datetime.strptime` and pass the format string.

Comment: I get an error stating 'length of values does not match length of index'

Comment: @bpr apologies, just realised that would only work for a single row df, have modified to use `datetime.datetime.strptime` instead which will assign a scalar value to all the rows

Comment: No worries, thank you for all your help! I appreciate you taking the time to help sort out my code!